# Informe de error ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to enter the variables inside the table `INFORME_VENTA`.
Below is my code:

```
VARIABLE B_ANIO VARCHAR2(8);

EXECUTE :B_ANIO := '042018'; 

DECLARE

V_CLIENTE_ID CLIENTES.CLIENTE_ID%TYPE;
V_NOMBRE_CIA CLIENTES.NOMBRE_CIA%TYPE;
V_NRO_BOLETA BOLETAS.NRO_BOLETA%TYPE;

BEGIN

LOOP

SELECT C.CLIENTE_ID , C.NOMBRE_CIA , B.NRO_BOLETA 
INTO V_CLIENTE_ID , V_NOMBRE_CIA , V_NRO_BOLETA 
FROM BOLETAS B JOIN ORDENES O JOIN CLIENTES C 
ON (C.CLIENTE_ID = O.ORDEN_ID)
ON (B.NRO_BOLETA = O.ORDEN_ID);

INSERT INTO INFORME_VENTA 
VALUES(:B_ANIO , V_CLIENTE_ID , V_NOMBRE_CIA , V_NRO_BOLETA);

END LOOP;

END;
```

I want to put the variables inside the `informe_venta` table but I get the following error

```
Informe de error -
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at line 11
01422. 00000 -  "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows"
*Cause:    The number specified in exact fetch is less than the rows returned.
*Action:   Rewrite the query or change number of rows requested
```

Comment: Removed `SQL Server` tag

Answer (score 2):

Why do you use PL/SQL? A simple `INSERT` is capable of doing the whole job:

```
insert into informe_venta
  select :b_anio, c.cliente_id , c.nombre_cia , b.nro_boleta 
  from boletas b join ordenes o 
    on b.nro_boleta = o.orden_id
  join clientes c 
    on c.cliente_id = o.orden_id;
```

(In SQL*Plus you'd reference the B_ANIO variable with ampersand, `&b_anio`).

If it *has to be* PL/SQL, enclose the above `INSERT` into `BEGIN-END` and run it. Once again: you don't need a loop.

One more remark: I'd suggest you to name columns you're inserting into, such as

```
insert into informe_venta (anio, cliente_id, nombre_cia, nro_boleta)
  select ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of SELECT INTO statement use CURSOR against ORA-01422 error, as in the following block :

```
VARIABLE B_ANIO VARCHAR2(8);

EXECUTE :B_ANIO := '042018'; 

DECLARE

V_CLIENTE_ID CLIENTES.CLIENTE_ID%TYPE;
V_NOMBRE_CIA CLIENTES.NOMBRE_CIA%TYPE;
V_NRO_BOLETA BOLETAS.NRO_BOLETA%TYPE;

BEGIN

FOR R IN 
(
      SELECT C.CLIENTE_ID , C.NOMBRE_CIA , B.NRO_BOLETA  
        FROM BOLETAS B JOIN ORDENES O JOIN CLIENTES C 
          ON (C.CLIENTE_ID = O.ORDEN_ID)
          ON (B.NRO_BOLETA = O.ORDEN_ID);     
)
LOOP

  V_CLIENTE_ID := R.CLIENTE_ID;
  V_NOMBRE_CIA := R.NOMBRE_CIA;
  V_NRO_BOLETA := R.NRO_BOLETA;

 INSERT INTO INFORME_VENTA 
 VALUES(:B_ANIO , V_CLIENTE_ID , V_NOMBRE_CIA , V_NRO_BOLETA);    
END LOOP;

END;
```